# using PKG with featherjs app

Tags: feathersjs, zeit-pkg

Has anyone ever tried using `pkg` with `featherjs` before? I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I get the following error when running my executable:

```
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/../project/config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1172
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: root path required
    at Function.serveStatic [as static] (/snapshot/../project/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:40:11)
```

Not sure where to go from here if anyone has any guidance.

```
"bin": "src/index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run eslint && npm run mocha",
  "dev": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/",
  "eslint": "eslint src/. test/. --config .eslintrc.json",
  "mocha": "mocha test/ --recursive --exit",
  "start": "node src/",
  "pkg": "pkg . -t node9-macos-x64 --out-path pkg"
},
"pkg": {
  "assets": [
    "src/**/*",
    "public/**/*",
    "config/**/*",
    "node_modules/config/**/*.*"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "config/**/*.json"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) used by [@feathersjs/configuration](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/configuration.html) which trying to load `config/default.json` from the folder of the running application, not the the bundled package. You can either try building with the [NODE_CONFIG](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables#node_config) environment variable set to the content of `config/defualt.json` or remove `app.configure(configuration())` and `app.set` the configuration options your application needs, for example by requiring `config/default.json` (which should also work in theh packaged environment):

```
const config = require('../config/default.json');

Object.keys(config).forEach(key => {
  app.set(key, config[key]);
});
```